# Angular6: Memoizing function with Lodash gives error

Tags: angular, lodash, angular6, memoization

Expected behavior:

I have a pipe which takes an object and a type, and it returns a variable of that object, depending on which type. I want to memoize this function since it should always return the same value with the same parameters. The pipe should return a string of a number of linked entities.

Observed behavior:

An error gets thrown, saying `this.getDefaultEntityTypeForLinkedEntities is not a function`. I use this method in the method that gets memoized.

Code:

```
export class LinkCountPipe implements PipeTransform {

  public transform(linkCount: LinkCount, type: EntityType, via: EntityType): string {
    const memoGetLinkCount = _.memoize(this.getLinkCount);
    const result = memoGetLinkCount(linkCount, type, via);
    return result ? result.toString() : undefined;
  }

  public getLinkCount(linkCount: LinkCount, type: EntityType, via: EntityType): number {
    const someType = via ? via : this.getDefaultEntityTypeForLinkedEntities(type);
    switch (someType) {
      case EntityType.APPLICATION:
        return linkCount.nbApplications;
      case EntityType.ENTITLEMENT:
        return linkCount.nbEntitlements;
      case EntityType.PERMISSION:
        return linkCount.nbPermissions;
      case EntityType.ROLE:
        return linkCount.nbRoles;
      case EntityType.USER:
        return linkCount.nbUsers;
    }
  }

  public getDefaultEntityTypeForLinkedEntities(type: EntityType) {
    return DatatableSettings.getDefaultEntityTypeForLinkedEntities(type);
  }
}
```

Clarification:

I'm using entities in the application. Each entity is linked to other types of entities (I have users, roles, permission, ...). Each entity object contains a linkCount object which is fetched from the server and it contains for example for a user his linked roles, entitlements, and applications. In my HTML I use: `element.linkCount | linkcount: type : via`. The linkcount pure pipe is used for better performance. What it should do is the following: It takes the linkCount object of the entity, it passes the type of the entity (eg. a user), and a via (this is optional, it is used to show something else in the datatable than the default linked entities. Eg: User datatable and show the linked permissions instead of roles). It then just returns the correct variable of the linkCount object, according to the type.

Comment: Could you please post your end goal so that we know what you're trying to do ? I mean with an example

Comment: @trichetriche I edited my question for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having a `this` issue here as well as issue with the concept of the `memoize` in terms of the fact that you pass 3 parameters to it when it only uses the first one by default to form the `map cache key`.

The `this` problem comes from the fact that by default `momoize` is invoked with the **this binding of the memoized function**.

[See the _.memoize documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#memoize)

> By default, the first argument provided to the memoized function is
>   used as the map cache key. The func is invoked with the this binding
>   of the memoized function.